# Identify or count continuously repeated number (actually missing value: nan) in the list

Tags: python, run-length-encoding

Basically, I would like to identify whether the missing values in data set are continuously repeated or not. If there are countinously repeated missing values in the data set, I would like to know whether lengths of the each continuously repeated missing value sets are above certian number or not.

For example:

```
data =['1', '0', '9', '31', '11', '12', 'nan', '10', '44', '53', '12', '66', '99', '3', '2', '6.75833',....., 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', '3', '7', 'nan', 'nan']
```

In `data` above, the total number of `'nan'` would be 6 and it could be calculated with `data.count('nan')`. However, what I want to know is how much continuously the missing value can be repeated. For this data, the answer would be 3.

I apologize that I don't show my example code, but I am a very novice in this area and I couldn't have any idea for coding.

Any idea, help or tips would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you really using strings like `'nan'` or are you using `numpy.nan`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for [*itertools.groupby()*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> data =['1', '0', '9', '31', '11', '12', 'nan', '10', '44', '53', 
           '12', '66', '99', '3', '2', '6.75833', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 
           '3', '7', 'nan', 'nan']
>>> [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(data) if key == 'nan']
[1, 3, 2]
```

Note if your code actually has real NaNs instead of strings, the `if key == 'nan'`equality test should be replaced with `math.isnan(key)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will let you know after I try it.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try this one, which is faster:

```
grouped_L = [sum(1 for i in group) for k,group in groupby(L)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [pyrle](https://github.com/pyranges/pyrle) for speed. In this solution I replace nan with a number not in the data (-42). This is because nan is a difficult value for rles, as `np.nan != np.nan` and hence no nans are treated as consecutive.

```
import numpy as np

data =['1', '0', '9', '31', '11', '12', 'nan', '10', '44', '53', '12', '66', '99', '3', '2', '6.75833', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', '3', '7', 'nan', 'nan']
arr = np.array([np.float(f) for f in data])
assert not -42 in arr


from pyrle import Rle

r = Rle(arr)
arr[np.isnan(arr)] = -42
is_nan = r.values == -42
np.max(r.runs[is_nan])
# 3
```